# How to convert SQL query results into a python dictionary

Tags: python, sql, dictionary

Im having difficuty converting my results from a query into a python dictionary. Each dictionary is supposed to represent one student, the keys are the column name and the values are the corresponding values from the query, so far this is what I've come up with:

```
def all_students():
    qu= 'select * from students'
    crs.execute(qu)
    for row in crs:
        student= {"StudentNum":row[0], "StudentLastName":row[2], "StudentFirst Name":row[3}
    return student
```

But when i print it , it returns in correct information and everything is out of order, and it only displays one record :

```
{'StudentLastName': Jane, StudentNum: 'Smith  ', StudentFirst Name: '1612'}
```

Comment: Which library are you getting the cursor from?

Answer (score 29):

You can use `cursor.description` to get the column names and "zip" the list of column names with every returned row producing as a result a list of dictionaries:

```
desc = cursor.description
column_names = [col[0] for col in desc]
data = [dict(zip(column_names, row))  
        for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Note: use `itertools.izip` in place of `zip()` on Python2.

Comment: for the last line, you can do `for row in cursor` instead of `cursor.fetchall()` and get the same result.

Comment: looks like `itertools.izip` is not available in Python 3, simple `zip` works though

Comment: In Python 3 the built in zip does the same job as izip in 2.x (returns a generator instead of a list) but slightly faster as it's a built-in function.

Comment: Module 'itertools' has no 'zip' member

Comment: @RickLan sure, added a note for python3.

Comment: I used code as follows:

`desc = cur.description
    cols = [col[0] for col in desc]
    data = [dict(itertools.zip(cols, row))
       for row in cur.fetchall()]`

Still I get following error: 
`AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'zip'`


I think that is what Ri1a is trying to point out.

Comment: Calling zip() without using itertools works fine.

Comment: To be honest I don't see much value in using `itertools.izip` in Python2: queries would have to be returning vast numbers of columns to make the overhead worthwhile.

Answer (score 11):

At this time you probably solved your problem, but anyway:

If you're using mysql I think this is what you need:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html

As per definition: *A MySQLCursorDict cursor returns each row as a dictionary. The keys for each dictionary object are the column names of the MySQL result.*

So you must only set
crs = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, but that's the "go slow - all  python" connector.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this can help: 
http://codetrace.blogspot.com/2010/05/convert-query-result-to-dictionary-like.html

```
query_result = [ dict(line) for line in [zip([ column[0] for column in crs.description], row) for row in crs.fetchall()] ]

print query_result
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will help...

```
def all_students():
    qu= "select * from students"
    students = crs.execute(qu)
    students_data = []
    for row in students:
        student= {"StudentNum":row[0], "StudentLastName":row[2], "StudentFirst Name":row[3}
         students_data.append(student)

    final_data["students_info"] = students_data
    return final_data
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, you can try the following (there is no need to loop through `crs`, you can use `crs.fetchall()` directly, given that **the table content fits into your memory**):

`result_list_of_dict = [{'StudentNum': col1, 'StudentLastName': col2, 'StudentFirst Name': col3} for (col1, col2, col3) in crs.fetchall()]`

The resulted `result_list_of_dict` is a list of dictionary, each element (dictionary) will have 3 keys as you specified ('StudentNum', 'StudentLastName' and 'StudentFirst Name') with the associated values extracted from the SQL table.

**To extend:**

Basically, `cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples so as long as you list all values that are supposedly returned, you can modify the front part however you like. For example, the following code would work for a table of 5 columns which you would like to extract only the first 3:

`result_dict = {col1:(col2, col3) for (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) in cursor.fetchall()}`

The resulted `result_dict` in this case would be a dictionary instead.

Comment: Can you explain why this works?  What is this code doing and how is it answering the question?

Comment: I made changes to add relevance to the original question

Comment: Only this answer returns a dictionary; the others return list of dictionaries!

Answer (score 1):

the answer with the most votes is for python2, here is the answer for python3:

```
import itertools

desc = cursor.description
column_names = [col[0] for col in desc]
data = [dict(zip(column_names, row))  
        for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect your query to return a **single result** and you want all of the values in a dictionary by their column name you can use:

```py
def querySingle(sql, args):
    try:
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, args)
        for row in cursor:
            return dict((column[0],row[index]) for index, column in enumerate(cursor.description))
        return {}
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

For example `querySingle("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE id=%s", [1])` might return:

```py
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "type": "Alligator"
}
```

##### How it works

`cursor.description` returns an array of all the columns, of which each entry is an array of which the first value is the name of the column.  Using  `enumerate` on that gives each column along with its index. Then it is just a matter of creating the dictionary with the name from `column[0]` along with the data from `row[index]`. Returning in the for loop ensures that only the first row is processed.

Answer (score -1):

```
result = db_pool.execute(query, return_dict=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are coming from Harvard's cs50 course, a `SELECT` query returns a list of where each row is represented by a Python `dict` where the keys correspond to the column name and the values are from the table.

You don't need to convert it.