# MySQL dump a table or saving table contents as a python dictionary

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a very simple and small db table with 2 columns only: Id and name.
Given the id, I have to find and return the corresponding name. I want to save the contents in a dictionary and look for the corresponding value from there instead of querying the database each time.
I have came across this [How to convert SQL query results into a python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755505/how-to-convert-sql-query-results-into-a-python-dictionary) but they are aiming to save each row as a dict, whilst I think I do not need a list of dictionaries just a dict with key value pairs.

```
def get_name(db_conn):
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT id, name FROM table")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    d = {}
    for row in rows:
       id = row[0]
       name = row[1]
       d[id]= name
print(d)
```

What would be the best approach given the task I have?

Comment: Why are you appending?  Can multiple names associate to a single id?

Comment: Each id is associated to a single and unique name. I just do not know how to save the data in a dictionary, to avoid constant quering of the db. I have edited slightly the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary comprehensions should be straight forward enough...

```
d = { row[0]: row[1] for row in cursor.fetchall() }
```

or...

```
d = { id: name for (id, name) in cursor.fetchall() }
```

This processes every row in `cursor.fetchall()` and yields `key: value` pairs directly into a dictionary.

It's very similar to your loop, but the looping is done in C rather than natively in python.

Comment: Thank you, yes- that is more elegant and succinct solution.